# insertion sort in objective c is not returning appropriate result

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, insertion-sort

```
arr = [NSMutableArray array];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:54]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:34]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:61]];
for(int j=1;j< [arr count];j++)
{
    id key = [arr objectAtIndex:j];
    int i =j-1;

    while (i>-1 && [arr objectAtIndex:i] > key) {
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i+1 withObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
        i=i-1;
    }
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i+1 withObject:key];
}
NSLog(@"After Sorting %@",arr);
```

Please let me know where I am getting it wrong. I know about sorted nsmutable arry just for research purpose I am doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you are comparing two `NSNumber` pointers rather than the values of the `NSNumber` objects:

```
while (i>-1 && [arr objectAtIndex:i] > key) {
```

Should be:

```
while (i > -1 && [[arr objectAtIndex:i] intValue] > [key intValue]) {
```

Comment: sorry I was unmindful commening you back...It actually working with your code however why I added the previous comment cause when I add 0 its not working for everything else ...its doing good

Comment: Also note, that the latest runtime optimises `NSNumber` instances by using [tagged pointers](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html), so there's a chance that comparing pointers would also work up to a point, but in general, either drop back to `int` using `intValue` or if you don't know the original type stored in the `NSNumber`, then use `NSNumber`'s `compare:` method instead.

Comment: thanx for giving this valuable suggestion however what I just felt each time I ran the code it gives me a different set of numbers in array...so its not working.....

Comment: @Saty: I also added `0` and it is still working for me. Is this exactly the same code as you are using? Where are you getting the data from? Maybe for the benefit of the exercise, try using the built-in sort methods to see whether they are also giving you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is what's wrong : You don't want to compare `NSNumber` objects (which you are doing in `[arr objectAtIndex:i] > key`], comparing the pointers i.e. their location in memory), only their value in a given representation (for instance, as `int`s):

```
...
while (i>-1 && [[arr objectAtIndex:i] intValue] > [key intValue] ) {
...
```

This makes sense since the output values of the comparator (here, `<`) depends on the number representation :

```
[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.14] intValue] < [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.14159] intValue]
//Returns NO since 3==3, i.e. 3<3 is wrong
[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.14] doubleValue] < [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.14159] doubleValue] 
//Returns YES since 3.14<3.14159
```